# How to add a prefix to every row of a particular column in a CSV file via command line on Linux

Tags: csv, awk, text-editor, vi

I am trying to achieve the following.

File before editing.

```
column-1,  column-2,  column-3,  column-4,  column-5
Row-1-c1,  Row-1-c2,  Row-1-c3,  Row-1-c4,  Row-1-c5
Row-2-c1,  Row-2-c2,  Row-2-c3,  Row-2-c4,  Row-2-c5
Row-3-c1,  Row-3-c2,  Row-3-c3,  Row-3-c4,  Row-3-c5
Row-4-c1,  Row-4-c2,  Row-4-c3,  Row-4-c4,  Row-4-c5
Row-5-c1,  Row-5-c2,  Row-5-c3,  Row-5-c4,  Row-5-c5
```

File after editing

```
column-1,   column-2,   column-3,           column-4,   column-5
Row-1-c1,   Row-1-c2,   Prefix-Row-1-c3,    Row-1-c4,   Row-1-c5
Row-2-c1,   Row-2-c2,   Prefix-Row-2-c3,    Row-2-c4,   Row-2-c5
Row-3-c1,   Row-3-c2,   Prefix-Row-3-c3,    Row-3-c4,   Row-3-c5
Row-4-c1,   Row-4-c2,   Prefix-Row-4-c3,    Row-4-c4,   Row-4-c5
Row-5-c1,   Row-5-c2,   Prefix-Row-5-c3,    Row-5-c4,   Row-5-c5
```

Notice that column-3 is the column that the prefix is added to each individual row except the column heading. 
I was wondering which editor would be the best editor to use and find out how to use the commands to get the desired result.

Comment: Are there any complicating factors in the data like commas appearing inside double quotes in the the values?  (`Row-N-C1, "Row-N-C2, Part A, Part B", Row-N-C3, Row-N-C4, Row-N-C5`). Also, how critical are the spaces in the sample data?  You seem to want the prefix to appear after the leading spaces after the comma that marks the start of column 3 — is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a better question would be "How many different tools could you use for the job?"

I'd probably go with `awk` as the easiest tool that does the job reasonably simply:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { print; OFS="," } NR > 1 { sub(/^ +/, "&Prefix-", $3); print }'
```

The `sub` operation adds `Prefix-` after the spaces at the start of column 3.  The code does not attempt to adjust the content of line 1 (the heading); if you want spaces added after `$3`, then I suppose this does the job (because of the placement of commas, you prefix the extra spaces to column 4 of line 1):

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { OFS=","; $4 = "       " $4; print }
         NR  > 1 { sub(/^ +/, "&Prefix-", $3); print }'
```

---

> Do you know how to do the same thing with sed?

Yes, like this:

```
sed -e '  1s/^\(\([^,]*,[[:space:]]*\)\{3\}\)/\1       /' \
    -e '2,$s/^\(\([^,]*,[[:space:]]*\)\{2\}\)/\1Prefix-/' "$@"
```

The first expression deals with the first line; it puts as many spaces as there are in the prefix (here that's "`Prefix-`" so it's 7 spaces) after the third column.  The second expression deals with the remaining lines; it adds the prefix before the third column.

To deal with column N instead of column 3, change the 3 to N and the 2 inside `\{2\}` to N-1.

I rechecked the second Awk script; it produces the correct output for me on the sample data from the question.  So, within its limitations, does the first Awk script.  Make sure you're using something other than the C shell (it gets upset by multi-line quoted strings), and that you were careful with your copying.

#### Example output

```
$ cat data
column-1,  column-2,  column-3,  column-4,  column-5
Row-1-c1,  Row-1-c2,  Row-1-c3,  Row-1-c4,  Row-1-c5
Row-2-c1,  Row-2-c2,  Row-2-c3,  Row-2-c4,  Row-2-c5
Row-3-c1,  Row-3-c2,  Row-3-c3,  Row-3-c4,  Row-3-c5
Row-4-c1,  Row-4-c2,  Row-4-c3,  Row-4-c4,  Row-4-c5
Row-5-c1,  Row-5-c2,  Row-5-c3,  Row-5-c4,  Row-5-c5
$ bash manglesed.sh data
column-1,  column-2,  column-3,         column-4,  column-5
Row-1-c1,  Row-1-c2,  Prefix-Row-1-c3,  Row-1-c4,  Row-1-c5
Row-2-c1,  Row-2-c2,  Prefix-Row-2-c3,  Row-2-c4,  Row-2-c5
Row-3-c1,  Row-3-c2,  Prefix-Row-3-c3,  Row-3-c4,  Row-3-c5
Row-4-c1,  Row-4-c2,  Prefix-Row-4-c3,  Row-4-c4,  Row-4-c5
Row-5-c1,  Row-5-c2,  Prefix-Row-5-c3,  Row-5-c4,  Row-5-c5
$ bash mangleawk.sh data
column-1,  column-2,  column-3,         column-4,  column-5
Row-1-c1,  Row-1-c2,  Prefix-Row-1-c3,  Row-1-c4,  Row-1-c5
Row-2-c1,  Row-2-c2,  Prefix-Row-2-c3,  Row-2-c4,  Row-2-c5
Row-3-c1,  Row-3-c2,  Prefix-Row-3-c3,  Row-3-c4,  Row-3-c5
Row-4-c1,  Row-4-c2,  Prefix-Row-4-c3,  Row-4-c4,  Row-4-c5
Row-5-c1,  Row-5-c2,  Prefix-Row-5-c3,  Row-5-c4,  Row-5-c5
$ cat manglesed.sh
sed -e '  1s/^\(\([^,]*,[[:space:]]*\)\{3\}\)/\1       /' \
    -e '2,$s/^\(\([^,]*,[[:space:]]*\)\{2\}\)/\1Prefix-/' "$@"
$ cat mangleawk.sh
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { OFS=","; $4 = "       " $4; print }
         NR  > 1 { sub(/^ +/, "&Prefix-", $3); print }' "$@"
$ awk -F, 'NR == 1 { print; OFS="," } NR > 1 { sub(/^ +/, "&Prefix-", $3); print }' data
column-1,  column-2,  column-3,  column-4,  column-5
Row-1-c1,  Row-1-c2,  Prefix-Row-1-c3,  Row-1-c4,  Row-1-c5
Row-2-c1,  Row-2-c2,  Prefix-Row-2-c3,  Row-2-c4,  Row-2-c5
Row-3-c1,  Row-3-c2,  Prefix-Row-3-c3,  Row-3-c4,  Row-3-c5
Row-4-c1,  Row-4-c2,  Prefix-Row-4-c3,  Row-4-c4,  Row-4-c5
Row-5-c1,  Row-5-c2,  Prefix-Row-5-c3,  Row-5-c4,  Row-5-c5
$
```

Comment: +1: Other option would be to simply pipe the output to `column -t`. `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{sub(/^ +/, "&Prefix-", $3)}1' file | column -t`

Comment: @jonathan: do you know how to do the same thing with sed?

Comment: @mOna: Yes, but it's horrid and the result is an inscrutable collection of backslashes and parentheses. Are you sure you really need to know? Is there a really good reason why you can't use Awk? If there's a compelling reason (like 'awk is not available'), then say so and I'll work it out (it isn't that hard; but it isn't readily comprehended).

Comment: actually, I'm really new in working with linuz and terminal... I think I need to read the difference between sed and awk.. I tried your command but It didnt work.. I think its my problem of lack of linux knowlede..

Comment: Not sure what you would have done for the Awk to fail.  See the update for how to do it in `sed`.  It isn't pretty visually; it is pretty effective, though.